# How to install specific Eclipse IDE fix in Rational Application Developer?

Tags: eclipse, git, ibm-rad

I'm using IBM Rational Application Developer v8.5.1, which is based on the Eclipse Platform v3.6.3.

There's a bug where the Delete key doesn't work in the Source view of some XML editors.
This seems like it might be a known bug such as https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=395642

Comment 19 in the linked bug links to some fixes in a Git repository. The one for my Eclipse version is http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/commit/?h=R3_6_maintenance&id=791b8203f5047b592378ae57bc6dfc2448b8bbe5

Is there a way to install this fix in my RAD installation from the Git repository?
Alternately, is there a specific update site from which to get this fix?

I've tried a few of the update sites that RAD includes by default, and can't see any updates relevant to this.

Comment: If you are under support then contact IBM and demand it fixed.

Comment: @Thorbjørn - upvoted because your comment made me think of a simpler solution, which I've given as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using IBM Installation Manager to check for updates to Rational Application Developer. A fix for this specific bug (Delete and other keys not working in XML source) was included in iFix 2 for Rational Application Developer v8.5.1.

Comment: Ah, yes it does not run automatically.